# Running one bit of code while another is computing

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this line of code:

```py
c_drive_dirs = [curdir for curdir, _, _ in os.walk(os.getcwd())]
```

while it's running I would like it to run a separate piece of code, for example:

```
print("/", end="\r")
print("-", end="\r")
print("\\", end="\r")
print("|", end="\r")
```

And I want this code to **continue running** *while* the 1st line of code is running, then run a different piece of code, for example:

```
print("")
```

In order to clear the screen of the loading effect

How would this be done?

(is there a python equivalent of C++'s `do-while` loop?)

Answer (score 1):

Both of these functions are blocking, threading/using asynchronous code will not allow both of them to run at the same time.

you can either use multiprocessing to run the print loop:

```
import os
import time
from multiprocessing import Process, Event
from itertools import cycle

def print_loading(event):
    c = cycle(["/", "-", "\\", "|"])
    while True:
        if event.is_set():
            break
        print(next(c), end="\r", flush=True)
        time.sleep(0.1)


def load_files():
    event = Event()
    p = Process(target=print_loading, args=(event,))
    p.daemon = True
    p.start()
    c_drive_dirs = [curdir for curdir, _, _ in os.walk(os.getcwd())]
    time.sleep(10)  # put this here for testing, remove in your code
    event.set()
    p.join()
    print(c_drive_dirs)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    load_files()
```

or just a simple function:

```
import os

def load_files():
    c = cycle(["/", "-", "\\", "|"])

    c_drive_dirs = []
    for curdir, _, _ in os.walk(os.getcwd()):
        c_drive_dirs.append(curdir)
        print(next(c), end="\r")
    print("\n")
    return c_drive_dirs

if __name__ == "__main__":
    res = load_files()
    print(res)
```

Or use a [library](https://pypi.org/project/progress/):

```
from progress.spinner import Spinner

spinner = Spinner('Loading ')

c_drive_dirs = []
for curdir, _, _ in os.walk(os.getcwd()):
    c_drive_dirs.append(curdir)
    spinner.next()
```